# cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter '_ in function call due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust

i have a vector of a struct

```rs
 let list = vec![
        ListenerList {
            listener: Pattern {
                cmd: "sum"
            },
            handler: |listener, connection| Box::pin(simple_handler(listener, connection))
        }
    ];
```

here is my struct

```rs
pub struct ListenerList<'a>{
    pub listener: Pattern<'a>,
    pub handler: fn(Subscription, &Connection) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = ()>>>
}
```

and here is my simple_handler function

```rs
async fn simple_handler(listener: Subscription, connection: &Connection){
    println!("work?")
}
```

when i compile it i get this error

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter '_ in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:19:54
   |
19 |             handler: |listener, connection| Box::pin(simple_handler(listener, connection))
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of the `handler` field of `ListenerList`, which has this type:

```rust
fn(Subscription, &Connection) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = ()>>>
```

Due to Rust's [default trait object lifetime rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes), it desugars to the trait object getting a `'static` bound, which we don't want:

```rust
fn(Subscription, &Connection) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = ()> + 'static>>
```

To fix this, specify the lifetime as `'_`:

```rust
fn(Subscription, &Connection) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = ()> + '_>>
```